# Why does realpath() need ~30 seconds for "//localhost/mysite/config/settings.yml"?

Tags: php, web, server, directory, filepath

After almost an hour of debugging some completely unreasonable execution times for requests that should have taken milliseconds, I found out that calling

```
$path = realpath("//localhost/mywebsite/config/some_config_file.yml");
```

would take almost 30 seconds when executed the first time and take milliseconds later on (for the same string). As expected, `$path` was set to *false*.

While I was able to remove the line (it was unnecessary anyway, please don't judge) and thus remove the bug, I would still like to know what happened as I'd like to grow as a developer.

1. What causes realpath() to take 30 seconds?
2. Why the much shorter time on subsequent requests? Is this OPcache using a precompiled value?

FYI: The requests were done on my local machine with xdebug activated. PHP 7.2, Win 10 and Apache.

Comment: could be the double slash. I don't think realpath is supposed to chat with anything else but FS, but // is usually a shorthand relative HTTP, eg http or https. Have you tried with a single slash instead, to prevent any type of confusion ?

Comment: Indeed. This snippet looks like someone thought it would resolve invalid URL lookalikes. And so did realpath. -- There's in fact some [caching involved](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/how-does-the-php-realpath-cache-work-and-how-to-configure-it). But you might have to [dig deep into the sources](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a7fe2570d3ce6915d4ea85c62c0f880ddc225ba7/Zend/zend_virtual_cwd.c#L1489) to find something relevant for this case.

Comment: @fab2s You are right that the _intended_ use of realpath is for FS, and understand that the string should never have been tested, but I was expecting a simple _false_ as the return value, but it feels weird that this process takes 30 seconds.

Comment: It then could be that realpath is trying to open an HTTPish connection that just times out after 30 sec, what is your http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion and from my experience i dont use realpath() anymore since years because of kind of this reasons. 
If the setup of your application is straight eg: include paths setup well or concrete setup of library path for autoloaders realpath is not really needed anymore. And this speeds up every thing.
Kind regards

edit btw: yes opcache in 7.2 does another ohh,ups :)

Comment: Thanks! I was using the function to remove any additional slashes _within_ the path that might have occurred due to concatenating parts of paths with unnecessary leading/trailing slashes, like $bad_path = "C:/xampp/" . "/this_file.txt"

Comment: you may add the hint for you: paths never add a slash, urls always add a slash :) i dont use win anymore but win can finaly accept posix path but should be implemented releativ not absolute when "win" in involved :)